# setTimeout not working with bounce.js and fullpage.js

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I'm working on a dummy site. I wanted to try my hand at a website with full-sized page section that take up the entire screen, like the homepage of [Tumblr](http://www.tumblr.com).

The title of my website ("Blocks") is displayed in 6 colored blocks across the center of the top page section, with each letter occupying its own colored block. Whenever you scroll down to another page section and back up to the first one, I want the colored blocks to begin their animations with 100ms between them.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var titleBlock1 = $(".titleBlock1");
    titleBlock2 = $(".titleBlock2");
    titleBlock3 = $(".titleBlock3");
    titleBlock4 = $(".titleBlock4");
    titleBlock5 = $(".titleBlock5");
    titleBlock6 = $(".titleBlock6");
    siteTitleLetter = $('.site-title-letter');
    bounce = new Bounce();

bounce.scale({
    from: { x: 0.1, y: 0.1 },
    to: { x: 1, y: 1 },
    duration: 1500,
    bounces: 5,
});


$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['#56BC8A', '#A77DC2', '#36465D', '#F2992E'],
    anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', 'lastPage'],
    menu: '#menu',
    resize: false,

    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
        //using index
        if(index == 1){
            for (var x = 1; x < 7; x++) {
                var delayTime = x * 100;

                setTimeout(function() {
                    console.log(x);
                    bounce.applyTo($('.titleBlock' + x));
                }, x*100);                  
            }
        }
    }
});

});
```

I've created a bounce animation using bounce.js and I'm trying to activate it whenever fullPage.js detects that one of the page sections has been loaded.

My question is: why isn't the setTimeout function working? Whenever I test this by scrolling back up into the top page section, it says that it cannot apply the bounce to an undefined element. However, when I remove the setTimeout and just try this:

```
afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
        //using index
        if(index == 1){
            for (var x = 1; x < 7; x++) {
                var delayTime = x * 100;

                bounce.applyTo($('.titleBlock' + x));
            }
        }
    }
```

It works just fine, it just of course doesn't include the delay that I want.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: (i guess) You need to use a closure: http://brackets.clementng.me/post/24150213014/example-of-a-javascript-closure-settimeout-inside

Comment: try setTimeout(function() { .. }, (parseInt(x)*100));

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys. Sadly, neither of those options worked.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using the default option `verticalCentered:true` and therefore your elements inside your sections will be wrapped by the plugin. You will need to use delegation or use your javascript inside the callback `afterRender` as suggested in [fullPage.js docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js):

> **afterRender()**
>
> This callback is fired just after the structure of the page is generated. This is the callback you want to use to initialise other plugins or fire any code which requires the document to be ready (as this plugin modifies the DOM to create the resulting structure).

Also adviced [in fullPage.js FAQs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/wiki/FAQ---Frecuently-Answered-Questions#my-other-plugins-dont-work-when-using-fullpagejs):

> **My other plugins don't work when using fullPage.js**
>
> **Short answer:** initialize them in the 'afterRender' callback of fullPage.js.
>
> **Explanation:** if you are using options such as 'verticalCentered:true' or 'overflowScroll:true' of fullPage.js, your content will be wrapped inside other elements changing its position in the DOM structure of the site. This way, your content would be consider as "dynamically added content" and most plugins needs the content to be originally on the site to perform their tasks. If you use the afterRender callback to initialise your plugins, then those elements are not going to suffer from any modification in the DOM structure anymore and will be consider to be originally in its place for the plugins you want to use from now on.